# linux : how to redirect to a file and to another process

Tags: linux, io, pipe

My command is the following

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

I need to see the commands output before passing them to another process.
How can I do that?

if I use

```
cmd1 > file1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

I guess I have to manage reading from the file in the process of cmd2 but what I want is having the standard output passed throw the different commands and to see what is passing throw.

Comment: check this answer for some references and examples: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `tee` command. It might be what you are looking for.
Example:

```
cmd1 | tee file1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you can use `tee` with `/dev/tty` as its parameter between commands that you execute:

```
ls -l  | tee /dev/tty | grep one_file -A2 | tee /dev/tty | grep something_else
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tee`command:

```
tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

Example:

```
echo hi | tee 1.txt | cat -n | tee 2.txt | grep hi
```